# Springboot | JSONB Postgres | Exception: Unable to load class [jsonb]

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jsonb

I'm using jsonb in springboot(2.1)+postgres(10.5)+hibernate(5.3.7).

Following are changes in file:

1. In pom.xml

`....
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    ....`

2. Entity definition:

```

```
@Entity(name = "Event")
@Table(name = "event")
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "int-array", typeClass = IntArrayType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonb-node", typeClass = JsonNodeBinaryType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "json-node", typeClass = JsonNodeStringType.class),
})
public class Event {

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private List<Location> alternativeLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

```

On running springboot application it given below error:

 `nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [jsonb]`

All other settings are standard sprintboot settings working with postgres. Post creation of this above error was coming.

Please let me know possible reason for same, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this?

Comment: Not exact solution, but the way i'm able to proceed right now is to change "private List<Location> alternativeLocations" to "private JsonNode alternativeLocations", didn't get time to dig deeper for better solution, This works good, but would be missing Object type checks

Comment: I'm going to use JDBC, using Hibernate is more hassle than anything. It really does not save development time. Hibernate has less performance also

Answer (score 18):

I am using a more current release 2.4.3 of the hibernate-types-52 classes and was getting the same error.

I resolved it by using only the single typedef I needed on my entity class.

```
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
```

Postgres 9.4, Java 11, Hibernate 5.3.7

```
@Entity(name = "audit")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Audit {
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name="audit_data", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Map<String,Object> auditData;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

public class ProjectPostgreSQL95Dialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect{

```
public ProjectPostgreSQL95Dialect() {
    this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonb");
}
```

}

in application.properties file replace below.

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect

replace

hibernate.dialect=com.ashok.config.PostgreSQL95Dialect

Comment: should that rather be: hibernate.dialect=com.ashok.config.ProjectPostgreSQL95Dialect ?

Comment: there is also the need to add 
@TypeDefs({@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)})
on top of every entity that will implement jsonb type definition. otherwise the hibernate wont know that entity is implementing it.

Comment: what should be hibernate implementation/version?

Answer (score 0):

what I will recommend is :

create a class that registers that datatype in your dialect

// remember I'm assuming you are using Postgres DB. Replace the

> extends PostgreSQL94Dialect

with the dialect of your DB.

```
public class MyPostgreSQL94Dialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {
    public MyPostgreSQL94Dialect() {
        this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonb");
    }
}
```

next in your application.properties configure your app's spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect={java_path_to_this_class}.MyPostgreSQL94Dialect
```

after the above has been completed
Make sure every entity that will use the jsonb defined in your Dialect is declared on those entities will now understand the type definition

```
@Data
@TypeDefs({@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)})
public class Event implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private List<Location> alternativeLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();
}
```